# Using multiple columns in a join on same field in second table

Tags: mysql

Consider the following :

```
**Table 1 - record**
id (int primary key),
addedby (int),
editedby (int)

**Table 2 - users**
id (int primary),
name (shorttext)

**Sample Records**
record
0 1 1
1 1 2

users
1 user1
2 user2
```

What I need is so do a join to to be able to show the following :

```
record.id, users.addedby, users.editedby
```

I tried, amongst others, the following :

```
select record.id, users.name, users.name from record left join users on record.addedby=users.id left join users on record.editedby=users.id
```

However, it's not even logical that that will work, so I am a bit stuck.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You were quite close.  Just need to use table aliases -- see the answer(s) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliasses:

```
select record.id, users1.name, users2.name 
from record 
left join users users1 on record.addedby=users1.id 
left join users users2 on record.editedby=users2.id
```

Comment: This was very close. It give give me matching records, but returned fields with NULL values where a match was not found, i.e. the users did not exist in the user table.

Comment: that would be due to the left joins instead of inner joins. to be fair you used left in your example. if your data was referentially consistent it wouldnt mater which of the joins you used in this case

Comment: Actually, now that I have added the extra fields this is the more correct answer, otherwise I would miss some rows if no user was found. In the real world scenario this is unlikely to happen, but best to cater for it methinks. Thanks

Comment: it should never happen - both addedby and editedby should be foreign keys referencing the user table

Comment: "Should", I agree, but what if a user gets deleted down the line? Something else I need to cater for methinks.

Comment: Flag the user as deleted with another column. No need to ever remove the row

Comment: Actually come to think of it you'd be better off having a separate table to record edits otherwise you only ever keep the most recent. If you're going to audit changes you may as well do it properly

Answer (score 2):

Just join the same table twice. Nothing unusual. You just have to alias the tables to be able to refer to them independently.

```
select r.id, u1.name added, u2.name editor
  from record r
    inner join user u1
      on r.addedby = u1.id
    inner join user u2
      on r.editedby = u2.id
```

[heres a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49ed0/1)

Comment: thanks, although i'm suddenly curious as to why you changed your mind on which answer to accept

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I think the main reason was just a shortcoming in my question. Please see my comments to Jens, as it just worked better once I added the rest of the fields. Sorry about that..

Comment: fair enough. it just didnt make sense to me at all that a record could be added or edited by someone who doesnt exist